# Why are my string tokens not getting printed? (strtok)

Tags: c, string, strtok

In this code, I'm taking a credit card number (which is datatype char) that has 12 digits that have spaces (eg: 1254 6789 4331). I want to split the string where the spaces are but when I ran the code on the command prompt, only the first 4 digits get printed (eg: 1254). There were no errors on the command prompt so I'm a little confused about why the code is not working. I would appreciate it if someone could help me, Thanks!

Code:

```
    '''

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main() {
       char string[20];
       printf("Please enter your credit card number: ");
       scanf("%s",string);
       // Extract the first token
       char * token = strtok(string," ");
       // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
       while( token != NULL ) 
       {
          printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
          token = strtok(NULL," ");
       }

       return 0;
    }

    '''
```

Comment: Because you don't seem to understand what `%s` actually does. It reads a whitespace-delimited string. If you added just one line of code to your program, `puts(string);`, immediately after your `scanf` call , it will become obvious what is transpiring. I submit you *really* want to use `fgets`, not `scanf` (both of which you should read and understand the behaviors and differences therein).

Comment: `for(char *tk=string;( tk=strtok(tk, " ") ) != NULL; tk=NULL)` !!! Usage should reflect the design of the functions. (And 20 is a tiny buffer for the card no. string... Taking chances...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
       scanf("%15[^\n]",string);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Why is there used the magic number 15?

Comment: Its not storing the whole 12 digits, only 4 digits are getting stored in your variable because of space in between. %s treats blank space as a string termination.Try printf("%s",string) after your scanf statement you will know.

Comment: @VikramAditya If its not too much trouble can you explain what happens in this line:    
    scanf("%15[^\n]",string);

Comment: %15[^\n] means it will continue accepting up to 15 characters except \n i.e. new line .In short scanf will accept all characters except new line which you get when to press enter key. 15 is for overflow safety you can use 20 also.